# Put math at the end of display

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsart

I'm trying to emulate the following behaviour i.e. the `$(r \in \mathcal N)$` at the end of the line.

[image]

I'd like to know how to do this in `\[ \]`, equation and align environments. I'm using amsart.

EDIT: It is posible to do the dual for non amsart? put something in the begin of the line?

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible, but not good style, in my opinion.

Comment: Use the `flalign` environment, but I agree with @egreg.

Comment: Considering that amsart puts the numbering to the left by default, I don't see the problem, could you elaborate a little why is bad style?

Comment: The `r\in\mathfrak{N}` condition should go either before the display, or near the second part. It makes no sense to push it to the right margin.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit hacky and overrides all the nice measuring mechanisms from `amsmath`, but it should be prety relialble in most of the cases. Note that the solution is sensible to the `leqno` and `reqno` options.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tagedequation}[1]{%
  \gdef\@tempa{#1}
  \refstepcounter{equation}
  (\iftagsleft@\theequation\else\(\@tempa\)\fi)\hfill\(
}{%
  \)\hfill(\iftagsleft@\(\@tempa\)\else\theequation\fi)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tagedequation}{r\in\mathfrak{N}}
  \theta' = \gamma\theta,\quad r'=r
\end{tagedequation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start.  I've shown two varieties depending on your desires for centering the content.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{flalign}
\phantom{(r\in\mathfrak{N})}&&\theta' = \gamma\theta,
  \quad r'=r&&(r\in\mathfrak{N})
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
&&\theta' = \gamma\theta,
  \quad r'=r&&(r\in\mathfrak{N})
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]